# momentJS know previous, current or next day after timezone conversion

Tags: javascript, date, time, ecmascript-6, momentjs

In below example, I am converting a time (`t`) from ACT to PST. Now, for this particular example I know that `t2` is 19 hours behind (If we consider `t1` to be on Monday-14:00:00 then `t2` is Sunday-19:00:00).

In my use-case, its not always going to be from ACT to PST. Source(`t1`) and destination(`t2`) are going to be dynamic timezone values. So, after conversion `t2` could be

- one day behind (i.e. if `t1` is Monday then `t2` is Sunday)
- is same day
  (i.e. if `t1` and `t2` are Monday)
- one day ahead (i.e. if `t1` is Monday
  then `t2` is Tuesday)

**Example:**

`let t = "14:00:00";

let t1 = moment.tz("2001-01-01" + t, 'Australia/Sydney');   // 14:00 ACT
let t2 = moment.tz("2001-01-01" + t, 'Australia/Sydney').utc().tz('US/Pacific');   //19:00 PST (19 hrs behind to ACT)`

Is there a way to figure out the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example, you could do this:

```
const s1 = t1.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
const s2 = t2.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Then

```
if (s1 > s2) {
  // t2 is behind t1
} else if (s1 < s2) {
  // t2 is ahead of t1
} else {
  // same day
}
```